# How can I extract other API scopes from a passport callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I want to get the birthday of an user using Passport.js with the `passport-google-oauth20` strategy. Where do I get the response of this extra scope and how do I extract this information?

I am having success on extracting the profile and email from an user, but every other scope I try I cannot seem to find where it returns. I'm using some scopes from [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) (more specifically People API, which I already activated from Google Cloud Platform) and they do not appear in the Passport strategy callback (only profile and email).

This is where I setup passport and check what is returning

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(config, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);
    // outputs:
    // id: ...
    // displayName: ...
    // name: { ... }
    // emails: [ { ... } ]
    // photos: [ { ... } ]
    // _raw: ...
    // _json: ... (above info plus profile link and locale)

    ...
  })
);
```

Inside my routes I declare the scopes and redirect the user

```
router.get('/auth/google/', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read', 'profile', 'email']
}));

router.get('/auth/google/redirect/', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('http://localhost:2000/profile/' + req.user.id)
})
```

My node and npm versions currently are:

```
node --version
v8.12.0

npm --version
6.9.0
```

And my package versions are the following:

```
...
"express": "^4.16.4",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
...
```

From what I understand, I should be able to retrieve more information other than profile, email and openid with Passport and I understand that I need to get the API of the scope I want activated. What I do not understand is how to retrieve the info from that API in the callback function or how to retrieve that info at all.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Did you end up figuring out a solution??

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make it work... I suggest opening an issue in Passport's google auth strategy asking the creator for more info. Here's the gh repo: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2